# Passing Multiple Headers in Gatling

Tags: load-testing, gatling, scala-gatling, gatling-plugin, maven-gatling-plugin

Im new to Gatling tool, trying to pass multiple header value from another file but im facing error while compiling.

Code:

```
val header0 = List(Map(
    "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key" -> TestParameters.Keyvalue,
    "UserId" -> TestParameters.UserID
  ))
```

Error:

```
ingInformation.scala:22:13: type mismatch;
 found   : scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,java.io.Serializable]
 required: Map[String,String]
                        .headers(header0)
                                 ^
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you make `header0` a List[Map[String, String]]?

It should be a Map[String, String]:

```scala
val header0 = Map(
  "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key" -> TestParameters.Keyvalue,
  "UserId" -> TestParameters.UserID
)
```

Also, as explained in the [documentation](https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/http/request/#headers), header values must be Strings. So if `TestParameters.Keyvalue` or `TestParameters.UserID` are anything else, such as numbers, you must convert them, eg with `toString`.

Comment: found   : scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,java.io.Serializable]
 required: Map[String,String]
                        .headers(header0)
                                 ^
Still facing the same error

Comment: @SriramRAJASEKARAN It's problem with type of your keys. Look at the key type - there `java.io.Serializable` but there should be `String`

Comment: I've updated my answer. Yes, header values must be Strings. I guess you're mixing Strings and numbers.